# Qfieldsync : Using multiple field devices

Tags: qfield

I need to use Qfield to collect data from multiple field workers. Is this possible with Qfieldsync and if so what would the workflow be.

If I sync the first device with the desktop project what will be the result of synching the second device; will it overwrite the data from the first device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the QField Sync allows you to merge data from multiple devices on your desktop project without overwriting previous synchronization.

De facto, you have to clear QField projects, or add fresh projects, on the devices after each sync in order to avoid duplicating data on the next synchronization.